# Geocoding addresses with list of coordinates

Tags: qgis, geocoding

I have a list of addresses in Bavaria I want to geocode (about 20.000 addresses) and use the coordinates afterwards in QGIS for analyzing.

As I don´t want to do it with google API or similar (because of limited number of addressed per day, data protection etc.) I´m looking for other possibilities.

I do have a file of coordinates of every house in Bavaria - so it wold be theoretical possible to match the addresses with this file. The problem is, that the file with the coordinates is quite big (450MB, 3.500.000 datapoints). When I´m loading it into QGIS it´s nearly impossible to edit it...

Is there any idea how I can deal with this topic?

Comment: you can request multiple google API keys and break your data into chunks and geocode using the MMQGIS plugin. What is it about data protection that are you referencing? House addresses are public information. I used this method to geocode 35k addresses in a day.

Answer (score 2):

The OpenStreetMap tool [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Examples) can be used for what you want. The linked article explains how to use one of the services or set up your own. Depending on which service provider you use, you might want to split your data into smaller chunks, so you don't max out daily quotas.

And as a small hint for your second approach: When opening such large data in QGIS, try and disable the `Render` option (can be found in the lower right of the window). This frees a lot of your system's resources. You won't be able to see anything on the UI, but you can still perform the joins you need.

Answer (score 0):

The University of Texas has an automated process that might work: http://geoservices.tamu.edu/

Comment: USA only. OP mentioned Bavaria

Comment: Sorry. I thought that they did more than just us.  Is it possible to capture lat/lon data from Goolge Maps? What about Google Earth or Pro?